# Can anyone confirm if this cyanogen ROM is for my phone?

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, installation

I have been looking for a custom ROM for my device.

My device is Zenfone 2 Laser ZE500KL. There seems to be none.

Could I successfully instal this release?: https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=Z00L

It's not Z00E, but I was wondering if it could work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/zenfone-2-laser/general/index-zenfone-2-laser-variants-t3369569) it's not ROM for your device you have models and their code names in first post. It will maybe will work if you do some changes, but flashing the file as is, is not recomanded it may brick your device or maybe not you'll won't know..